# Counting Responses of Radio Buttons

Tags: angular, typescript

I have this html page and it has 5 questions. I'm trying to redirect the user to different pages according to their responses. So I'm trying to capture "yes" responses here. Tried caputuring responses as 1(for yes) 0(for no).But couldn't properly add them together(1+1 was 11). I'm very new to progamming. Using angular for the project. It's my first question here. Can someone help?

```html
<!-- quizlist -->
<div class="row">
  <div class="col-lg-8 col-md-11 mx-auto">
    <div class="shadow">
      <div class="content-box mt-4">
        <div class="quizlist">
          <h3>Take the inflammatory Back Pain Quiz</h3>
          <div class="item">
            <div class="row align-items-center">
              <div class="col-lg-10 col-md-10">
                <p>Did your backpain and stiffness start before the age of 45?</p>
              </div>
              <div class="col-lg-2 col-md-2">
                <div class=" float-end">
                  <div class="radio-tile-group d-flex">
                    <div class="input-container yes">
                      <input id="yes" class="radio-button" type="radio" name="radio1" />
                      <div class="radio-tile">
                        <div class="icon yes-icon">
                          <svg fill="#000000" height="24" viewBox="0 0 24 24" width="24" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
                              <path d="M0 0h24v24H0z" fill="none" />
                              <path d="M13.5 2l-7.5 7.5-3.5-3.5-2.5 2.5 6 6 10-10z" />
                            </svg>
                        </div>
                        <label for="yes" class="radio-tile-label"></label>
                      </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="input-container no">
                      <input id="no" class="radio-button" type="radio" name="radio1" />
                      <div class="radio-tile">
                        <div class="icon no-icon">
                          <svg fill="#000000" height="24" viewBox="0 0 24 24" width="24" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
                              <path d="M0 0h24v24H0z" fill="none" />
                              <path d="M15.854 12.854c-0-0-0-0-0-0l-4.854-4.854 4.854-4.854c0-0 0-0 0-0 0.052-0.052 0.090-0.113 0.114-0.178 0.066-0.178 0.028-0.386-0.114-0.529l-2.293-2.293c-0.143-0.143-0.351-0.181-0.529-0.114-0.065 0.024-0.126 0.062-0.178 0.114 0 0-0 0-0 0l-4.854 4.854-4.854-4.854c-0-0-0-0-0-0-0.052-0.052-0.113-0.090-0.178-0.114-0.178-0.066-0.386-0.029-0.529 0.114l-2.293 2.293c-0.143 0.143-0.181 0.351-0.114 0.529 0.024 0.065 0.062 0.126 0.114 0.178 0 0 0 0 0 0l4.854 4.854-4.854 4.854c-0 0-0 0-0 0-0.052 0.052-0.090 0.113-0.114 0.178-0.066 0.178-0.029 0.386 0.114 0.529l2.293 2.293c0.143 0.143 0.351 0.181 0.529 0.114 0.065-0.024 0.126-0.062 0.178-0.114 0-0 0-0 0-0l4.854-4.854 4.854 4.854c0 0 0 0 0 0 0.052 0.052 0.113 0.090 0.178 0.114 0.178 0.066 0.386 0.029 0.529-0.114l2.293-2.293c0.143-0.143 0.181-0.351 0.114-0.529-0.024-0.065-0.062-0.126-0.114-0.178z" />
                            </svg>
                        </div>
                        <label for="no" class="radio-tile-label"></label>
                      </div>
                    </div>
                  </div>
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
          <div class="item">
            <div class="row align-items-center">
              <div class="col-lg-10 col-md-10">
                <p>Did your pain and stiffness develop gradually, with symptoms peristing at least three months?</p>
              </div>
              <div class="col-lg-2 col-md-2">
                <div class=" float-end">
                  <div class="radio-tile-group d-flex">
                    <div class="input-container yes">
                      <input id="yes" class="radio-button" type="radio" name="radio2" />
                      <div class="radio-tile">
                        <div class="icon yes-icon">
                          <svg fill="#000000" height="24" viewBox="0 0 24 24" width="24" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
                              <path d="M0 0h24v24H0z" fill="none" />
                              <path d="M13.5 2l-7.5 7.5-3.5-3.5-2.5 2.5 6 6 10-10z" />
                            </svg>
                        </div>
                        <label for="yes" class="radio-tile-label"></label>
                      </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="input-container no">
                      <input id="no" class="radio-button" type="radio" name="radio2" />
                      <div class="radio-tile">
                        <div class="icon no-icon">
                          <svg fill="#000000" height="24" viewBox="0 0 24 24" width="24" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
                              <path d="M0 0h24v24H0z" fill="none" />
                              <path d="M15.854 12.854c-0-0-0-0-0-0l-4.854-4.854 4.854-4.854c0-0 0-0 0-0 0.052-0.052 0.090-0.113 0.114-0.178 0.066-0.178 0.028-0.386-0.114-0.529l-2.293-2.293c-0.143-0.143-0.351-0.181-0.529-0.114-0.065 0.024-0.126 0.062-0.178 0.114 0 0-0 0-0 0l-4.854 4.854-4.854-4.854c-0-0-0-0-0-0-0.052-0.052-0.113-0.090-0.178-0.114-0.178-0.066-0.386-0.029-0.529 0.114l-2.293 2.293c-0.143 0.143-0.181 0.351-0.114 0.529 0.024 0.065 0.062 0.126 0.114 0.178 0 0 0 0 0 0l4.854 4.854-4.854 4.854c-0 0-0 0-0 0-0.052 0.052-0.090 0.113-0.114 0.178-0.066 0.178-0.029 0.386 0.114 0.529l2.293 2.293c0.143 0.143 0.351 0.181 0.529 0.114 0.065-0.024 0.126-0.062 0.178-0.114 0-0 0-0 0-0l4.854-4.854 4.854 4.854c0 0 0 0 0 0 0.052 0.052 0.113 0.090 0.178 0.114 0.178 0.066 0.386 0.029 0.529-0.114l2.293-2.293c0.143-0.143 0.181-0.351 0.114-0.529-0.024-0.065-0.062-0.126-0.114-0.178z" />
                            </svg>
                        </div>
                        <label for="no" class="radio-tile-label"></label>
                      </div>
                    </div>
                  </div>
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
          <div class="item">
            <div class="row align-items-center">
              <div class="col-lg-10 col-md-10">
                <p>Did your backpain and stiffness start before the age of 45?</p>
              </div>
              <div class="col-lg-2 col-md-2">
                <div class=" float-end">
                  <div class="radio-tile-group d-flex">
                    <div class="input-container yes">
                      <input id="yes" class="radio-button" type="radio" name="radio3" />
                      <div class="radio-tile">
                        <div class="icon yes-icon">
                          <svg fill="#000000" height="24" viewBox="0 0 24 24" width="24" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
                              <path d="M0 0h24v24H0z" fill="none" />
                              <path d="M13.5 2l-7.5 7.5-3.5-3.5-2.5 2.5 6 6 10-10z" />
                            </svg>
                        </div>
                        <label for="yes" class="radio-tile-label"></label>
                      </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="input-container no">
                      <input id="no" class="radio-button" type="radio" name="radio3" />
                      <div class="radio-tile">
                        <div class="icon no-icon">
                          <svg fill="#000000" height="24" viewBox="0 0 24 24" width="24" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
                              <path d="M0 0h24v24H0z" fill="none" />
                              <path d="M15.854 12.854c-0-0-0-0-0-0l-4.854-4.854 4.854-4.854c0-0 0-0 0-0 0.052-0.052 0.090-0.113 0.114-0.178 0.066-0.178 0.028-0.386-0.114-0.529l-2.293-2.293c-0.143-0.143-0.351-0.181-0.529-0.114-0.065 0.024-0.126 0.062-0.178 0.114 0 0-0 0-0 0l-4.854 4.854-4.854-4.854c-0-0-0-0-0-0-0.052-0.052-0.113-0.090-0.178-0.114-0.178-0.066-0.386-0.029-0.529 0.114l-2.293 2.293c-0.143 0.143-0.181 0.351-0.114 0.529 0.024 0.065 0.062 0.126 0.114 0.178 0 0 0 0 0 0l4.854 4.854-4.854 4.854c-0 0-0 0-0 0-0.052 0.052-0.090 0.113-0.114 0.178-0.066 0.178-0.029 0.386 0.114 0.529l2.293 2.293c0.143 0.143 0.351 0.181 0.529 0.114 0.065-0.024 0.126-0.062 0.178-0.114 0-0 0-0 0-0l4.854-4.854 4.854 4.854c0 0 0 0 0 0 0.052 0.052 0.113 0.090 0.178 0.114 0.178 0.066 0.386 0.029 0.529-0.114l2.293-2.293c0.143-0.143 0.181-0.351 0.114-0.529-0.024-0.065-0.062-0.126-0.114-0.178z" />
                            </svg>
                        </div>
                        <label for="no" class="radio-tile-label"></label>
                      </div>
                    </div>
                  </div>
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
          <div class="item">
            <div class="row align-items-center">
              <div class="col-lg-10 col-md-10">
                <p>Did your pain and stiffness develop gradually, with symptoms peristing at least three months?</p>
              </div>
              <div class="col-lg-2 col-md-2">
                <div class=" float-end">
                  <div class="radio-tile-group d-flex">
                    <div class="input-container yes">
                      <input id="yes" class="radio-button" type="radio" name="radio4" />
                      <div class="radio-tile">
                        <div class="icon yes-icon">
                          <svg fill="#000000" height="24" viewBox="0 0 24 24" width="24" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
                              <path d="M0 0h24v24H0z" fill="none" />
                              <path d="M13.5 2l-7.5 7.5-3.5-3.5-2.5 2.5 6 6 10-10z" />
                            </svg>
                        </div>
                        <label for="yes" class="radio-tile-label"></label>
                      </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="input-container no">
                      <input id="no" class="radio-button" type="radio" name="radio4" />
                      <div class="radio-tile">
                        <div class="icon no-icon">
                          <svg fill="#000000" height="24" viewBox="0 0 24 24" width="24" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
                              <path d="M0 0h24v24H0z" fill="none" />
                              <path d="M15.854 12.854c-0-0-0-0-0-0l-4.854-4.854 4.854-4.854c0-0 0-0 0-0 0.052-0.052 0.090-0.113 0.114-0.178 0.066-0.178 0.028-0.386-0.114-0.529l-2.293-2.293c-0.143-0.143-0.351-0.181-0.529-0.114-0.065 0.024-0.126 0.062-0.178 0.114 0 0-0 0-0 0l-4.854 4.854-4.854-4.854c-0-0-0-0-0-0-0.052-0.052-0.113-0.090-0.178-0.114-0.178-0.066-0.386-0.029-0.529 0.114l-2.293 2.293c-0.143 0.143-0.181 0.351-0.114 0.529 0.024 0.065 0.062 0.126 0.114 0.178 0 0 0 0 0 0l4.854 4.854-4.854 4.854c-0 0-0 0-0 0-0.052 0.052-0.090 0.113-0.114 0.178-0.066 0.178-0.029 0.386 0.114 0.529l2.293 2.293c0.143 0.143 0.351 0.181 0.529 0.114 0.065-0.024 0.126-0.062 0.178-0.114 0-0 0-0 0-0l4.854-4.854 4.854 4.854c0 0 0 0 0 0 0.052 0.052 0.113 0.090 0.178 0.114 0.178 0.066 0.386 0.029 0.529-0.114l2.293-2.293c0.143-0.143 0.181-0.351 0.114-0.529-0.024-0.065-0.062-0.126-0.114-0.178z" />
                            </svg>
                        </div>
                        <label for="no" class="radio-tile-label"></label>
                      </div>
                    </div>
                  </div>
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
          <div class="item">
            <div class="row align-items-center">
              <div class="col-lg-10 col-md-10">
                <p>Did your backpain and stiffness start before the age of 45?</p>
              </div>
              <div class="col-lg-2 col-md-2">
                <div class=" float-end">
                  <div class="radio-tile-group d-flex">
                    <div class="input-container yes">
                      <input id="yes" class="radio-button" type="radio" name="radio5" />
                      <div class="radio-tile">
                        <div class="icon yes-icon">
                          <svg fill="#000000" height="24" viewBox="0 0 24 24" width="24" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
                              <path d="M0 0h24v24H0z" fill="none" />
                              <path d="M13.5 2l-7.5 7.5-3.5-3.5-2.5 2.5 6 6 10-10z" />
                            </svg>
                        </div>
                        <label for="yes" class="radio-tile-label"></label>
                      </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="input-container no">
                      <input id="no" class="radio-button" type="radio" name="radio5" />
                      <div class="radio-tile">
                        <div class="icon no-icon">
                          <svg fill="#000000" height="24" viewBox="0 0 24 24" width="24" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
                              <path d="M0 0h24v24H0z" fill="none" />
                              <path d="M15.854 12.854c-0-0-0-0-0-0l-4.854-4.854 4.854-4.854c0-0 0-0 0-0 0.052-0.052 0.090-0.113 0.114-0.178 0.066-0.178 0.028-0.386-0.114-0.529l-2.293-2.293c-0.143-0.143-0.351-0.181-0.529-0.114-0.065 0.024-0.126 0.062-0.178 0.114 0 0-0 0-0 0l-4.854 4.854-4.854-4.854c-0-0-0-0-0-0-0.052-0.052-0.113-0.090-0.178-0.114-0.178-0.066-0.386-0.029-0.529 0.114l-2.293 2.293c-0.143 0.143-0.181 0.351-0.114 0.529 0.024 0.065 0.062 0.126 0.114 0.178 0 0 0 0 0 0l4.854 4.854-4.854 4.854c-0 0-0 0-0 0-0.052 0.052-0.090 0.113-0.114 0.178-0.066 0.178-0.029 0.386 0.114 0.529l2.293 2.293c0.143 0.143 0.351 0.181 0.529 0.114 0.065-0.024 0.126-0.062 0.178-0.114 0-0 0-0 0-0l4.854-4.854 4.854 4.854c0 0 0 0 0 0 0.052 0.052 0.113 0.090 0.178 0.114 0.178 0.066 0.386 0.029 0.529-0.114l2.293-2.293c0.143-0.143 0.181-0.351 0.114-0.529-0.024-0.065-0.062-0.126-0.114-0.178z" />
                            </svg>
                        </div>
                        <label for="no" class="radio-tile-label"></label>
                      </div>
                    </div>
                  </div>
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="text-end mt-3">
          <a href="/recommendation" class="btn primary">View Score</a>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="bottom-detail">
        <p>This quiz is adapted from the ASAS (The Assessment of SpondyloArthritis International Society) Criteria for identifying inflammatory back pain.</p>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>

</div>
```

Comment: `But couldn't properly add them together(1+1 was 11).` Sounds like you are trying to add strings together because the `+` operator when used on strings literally connects the two strings.

Comment: Please also ensure that your example code is as `minimal` as possible, but still reproducing your problem. Your example both isn't very readable and also doesn't show the problem.

Answer (score 0):

You can declare an object type that will contain questions and answers:

```js
type Question = {
  question: string;
  answer?: boolean;
};
```

The question mark on `answer?` means the property can be `undefined`. We'll use that to represent an unanswered question.

Then in your component you can make an array of questions:

```
export class AppComponent {
  questions: Question[] = [
    {
      question: 'Did your backpain and stiffness start before the age of 45?',
      answer: undefined,
    },
    {
      question:
        'Did your pain and stiffness develop gradually, with symptoms peristing at least three months?',
      answer: undefined,
    },
    {
      question:
        'Did your pain and stiffness develop gradually, with symptoms peristing at least three months?',
      answer: undefined,
    },
    {
      question: 'Did your backpain and stiffness start before the age of 45?',
      answer: undefined,
    },
  ];

  setAnswer(q: Question, a: boolean) {
    q.answer = a;
  }
}
```

I've also included a function to set an answer which we'll attach to the `click` event of each radio button.

We can use the `ngFor` directive to repeat some html for each question.

```html
<div class="row">
  <div class="col-lg-8 col-md-11 mx-auto">
    <div class="shadow">
      <div class="content-box mt-4">
        <div class="quizlist">
          <h3>Take the inflammatory Back Pain Quiz</h3>
          <ng-container *ngFor="let question of questions; let i = index">
            <div class="item">
              <div class="row align-items-center">
                <div class="col-lg-10 col-md-10">
                  <p>
                    {{ question.question }}
                  </p>
                </div>
                <div class="col-lg-2 col-md-2">
                  <div class="float-end">
                    <div class="radio-tile-group d-flex">
                      <div class="input-container yes">
                        <input
                          id="yes{{ i }}"
                          class="radio-button"
                          type="radio"
                          name="radio{{ i }}"
                          (click)="setAnswer(question, true)"
                        />
                        <div class="radio-tile">
                          <div class="icon yes-icon">
                            <svg
                              fill="#000000"
                              height="24"
                              viewBox="0 0 24 24"
                              width="24"
                              xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"
                            >
                              <path d="M0 0h24v24H0z" fill="none" />
                              <path
                                d="M13.5 2l-7.5 7.5-3.5-3.5-2.5 2.5 6 6 10-10z"
                              />
                            </svg>
                          </div>
                          <label
                            for="yes{{ i }}"
                            class="radio-tile-label"
                          ></label>
                        </div>
                      </div>
                      <div class="input-container no">
                        <input
                          id="no{{ i }}"
                          class="radio-button"
                          type="radio"
                          name="radio{{ i }}"
                          (click)="setAnswer(question, false)"
                        />
                        <div class="radio-tile">
                          <div class="icon no-icon">
                            <svg
                              fill="#000000"
                              height="24"
                              viewBox="0 0 24 24"
                              width="24"
                              xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"
                            >
                              <path d="M0 0h24v24H0z" fill="none" />
                              <path
                                d="M15.854 12.854c-0-0-0-0-0-0l-4.854-4.854 4.854-4.854c0-0 0-0 0-0 0.052-0.052 0.090-0.113 0.114-0.178 0.066-0.178 0.028-0.386-0.114-0.529l-2.293-2.293c-0.143-0.143-0.351-0.181-0.529-0.114-0.065 0.024-0.126 0.062-0.178 0.114 0 0-0 0-0 0l-4.854 4.854-4.854-4.854c-0-0-0-0-0-0-0.052-0.052-0.113-0.090-0.178-0.114-0.178-0.066-0.386-0.029-0.529 0.114l-2.293 2.293c-0.143 0.143-0.181 0.351-0.114 0.529 0.024 0.065 0.062 0.126 0.114 0.178 0 0 0 0 0 0l4.854 4.854-4.854 4.854c-0 0-0 0-0 0-0.052 0.052-0.090 0.113-0.114 0.178-0.066 0.178-0.029 0.386 0.114 0.529l2.293 2.293c0.143 0.143 0.351 0.181 0.529 0.114 0.065-0.024 0.126-0.062 0.178-0.114 0-0 0-0 0-0l4.854-4.854 4.854 4.854c0 0 0 0 0 0 0.052 0.052 0.113 0.090 0.178 0.114 0.178 0.066 0.386 0.029 0.529-0.114l2.293-2.293c0.143-0.143 0.181-0.351 0.114-0.529-0.024-0.065-0.062-0.126-0.114-0.178z"
                              />
                            </svg>
                          </div>
                          <label
                            for="no{{ i }}"
                            class="radio-tile-label"
                          ></label>
                        </div>
                      </div>
                    </div>
                  </div>
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>
          </ng-container>
          <div class="text-end mt-3">
            <a href="/recommendation" class="btn primary">View Score</a>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="bottom-detail">
          <p>
            This quiz is adapted from the ASAS (The Assessment of
            SpondyloArthritis International Society) Criteria for identifying
            inflammatory back pain.
          </p>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Double braces `{{ }}` allow you to put the variables from your component into the html template. Notice how I use `i` (the index of the questions array) to give each radio button a unique id, and each group a unique name.

Notice I've attached function calls to the `click` event of each radio button.

Here's a function we can use to count up the answers and log them:

```js
  count() {
    let yes = 0;
    let no = 0;
    let unanswered = 0;
    for (const q of this.questions) {
      if (q.answer) yes++;
      else if (q.answer === false) no++;
      else unanswered++;
    }
    console.log('You answered yes', yes, 'times.');
    console.log('You answered no', no, 'times.');
    console.log('You did not answer', unanswered, 'times.');
  }
```

And I'll attach them to a button for testing:

```html
<button (click)="count()">Log Result</button>
```

Here's a working example: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-ey19hv?file=src/app/app.component.ts

---

This is a primitive way of creating a form, nothing wrong with that, but you may want to do Angular's Forms tutorial: https://angular.io/guide/forms-overview

There are two main ways:

Template driven forms which are more html heavy: https://angular.io/guide/forms

Reactive forms which are more javascript heavy: https://angular.io/guide/reactive-forms

There's also pre-made components to make your life easier: https://material.angular.io/components/radio/overview